# How to allow a class to implement an interface only if it is serializable?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have an interface called "XMLControl", and I need every class that implements it to also implement `ISerializable`. Is there any OO approach to force this?

It may also be possible to put XMLControl as an abstract class although slightly less preferable. What's the best approach?

I was thinking of putting a static method in XMLControl like so:

`static void LoadFromXML(SerializableClass);`

but looking for better ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could make the `XMLControl` interface implement the `ISerializable` interface:

```
public interface IXmlControl: ISerializable
{
    ...
}
```

This way you are forcing all implementors of the `IXmlControl` interface to also implement `ISerializable`.

Also notice that standard .NET naming convention dictate that interface names should start with a capital `I`. So this interface would better be called `IXmlControl`.

Comment: Although I reccomend 'IXMLControl' due to recomended naming conventions.

Comment: Personally I'd go for `IXmlControl`.